# How can I update a document and insert a field using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm making a program that reads CNPJ (in Brazil it's called that, in the US there is something similar, the EIN)

I already have the data in my MongoDB. Now that we add a new field eg `Test` with the value `testtest`

how can I do this? Because the way I'm doing it, it's not working.

> ```
> collection.update_one({'Result': '0'},
>                       {"$set": {"Test": "testtest"}})
> ```

in the image below: I would like to insert the new data inside Lawsuits

[image]

Comment: So, you want to add `"Test": "testtest"` to the `"Lawsuits"` object in the first object of the `"Result"` array? Like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dR7WqRPxkLq)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `find` query inside `update_one` using `_id` so that you can get the exact match and then update it, it should work.

for reference:

```
collection.update_one({'_id': ObjectId(_id)},
                      {"$set": {"Test": "testtest"}})
```

Let me know if you have any additional requirement.